# Sharing cache between .NET Core Controller and SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, signalr

I have a legacy data store that is easily overloaded, with an ASP.NET Core v2.1 REST API layer on top of it. This REST API uses caching (an `IMemoryCache`) to reduce the instantaneous load on the data store.

Now I need to add some sort of round-robin like polling of the data store to keep items updated, aka "real-time updates". I'd like to utilize this same cache in the API Controller if possible, rather than have to add a whole other service (redis) to the application. The latter would require much more work due to changing our system architecture.

I've decided on using SignalR for these real-time updates. I've added a SignalR Hub to the REST API project. Browsers will subscribe to a specific data identifier (a group) and the system will notify those groups when items are updated. The strategy to poll the data store for this data is a different question. The data coming via SignalR is a small subset of the data the REST API provides.

But I would like to utilize the same cache in case two or more clients are requesting the same data within a short time period (say, 10 seconds).

Or, is this concern overblown?

Both classes are in the same project. The easiest way so far is to have each access this data individually (though each could have their own cache):

```
APIController ------- +------+            
                      | Data |            
SignalR ------------- +------+
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
APIController ------- Cache ---- +------+            
                        -        | Data |            
SignalR ----------------+        +------+
```

Now, I admit that looks like I just need redis or memcached, but redis is overkill for what I need here and involves red tape. Persistence is not needed so a memory cache works fine.

Can I do this with a shared static class/service injected in each? Or do I have an X-Y problem?

Comment: if you run the REST Api and Signalr in the same instance, you can implement IMemoryCache with or without IDistributedCache (if you plan to swap it with redis in the future)

Comment: They are in the same instance. I am using `IMemoryCache` currently, but I would like to share it with the SignalR hub. I don't see a way to share this, at least not via .NET Core's dependency injection.

Comment: Have you try using IDistributedCache? i just tested it, it can get data from controller and hub

Comment: I will have to look into that. I am not familiar with IDistributedCache, I thought there would be the same intraprocess problem I am having.

Comment: @FirdausKamaruddin I think I see the difference now, IDistributedCache is added as a service (to support potential persistence), where the IMemoryCache is just created on-demand.

Comment: yes. but IDistributedCache required your data to be serialized (since it need to store it), while IMemoryCache do not, read more here https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/issues/382